# list.getAdapter().getView(i, view, list) doesn't update my row

Tags: android, listview

I have button in my row layout that on click toggles its state (and its background resource).

On its onClickListener I update the corresponding, to this row, data and I call the

```
list.getAdapter().getView(i, view, list);
```

The adapter getView is called (having the updated data) but it does not update visually my visible row. Any ideas why ?

Note that when I scroll down and then back scroll up the row is being updated.

PS1: Calling the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() works but I do not want that since I want to update one single row.

PS2: I know that I could update the button of the row myself in its listener but I prefer to let the adapter do that for me, because the update of the row will become more complex later.

Comment: you cannot call `getView`, instead change your adapter's model data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Do you ever considered to "save" each view in an ArrayList or something so you can access it directly later? You can put this ArrayList on your adapter.

Comment: Directly call getView() is not recommended. Anyway, if you still want to use this approach, then give view.invalidate() a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling

```
list.getAdapter().getView(i, view, list);
```

is wrong. The system takes care of calling getView to update/render the ListView's content. You have to update the dataset used to *build* the ListView's content up, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: If you want to change specific row or range of rows then consider using recyclerview. With normal listview it's not possible as far as I know.